# How to optimize magento 2 performance at the first time?

Tags: magento2, performance

After deploying production mode, merge js and css, minify HTML, Compile codes, enable Opcodes, Gzip, enable all caches (except "Varnish caches"),

I still see magento2 consume about 6-15s for the first time. From the 2nd time, it works smoothly.

The question is **How I can improve performance for the first time request** ?
I used XAMPP, PHP7 on window 8.

Comment: Why do you need this? Or you mean that request than not in FPC is running in >5s?

Comment: Do you have the same problem like I have ? I thought Magento2 must be faster than it.  Yes, if a page is not already in FPC it must take more time to generate the caches for this page at the first time request. Do you have any ideas we can generate all page caches before that?

Comment: I don't have the same problem. On my test  VM (DigitalOcean 5$, 1core, 512 Mb ram) category page from sample data is opened ~ 0.5s  and ~ 0.1s with FPC

Comment: Do you think maybe because I use HDD instead of SSD can cause this problem ? Or because I used XAMPP on window ? Not sure why ? Maybe someone who uses HDD, and XAMPP on window can answer me this question.

Comment: Looks like Windows not best for M2. My best experience was installing linux with GUI in VirtualBox and use PHPStorm from vm

Comment: Yes. I see magento2 works faster in Linux environment.

Answer (score -2):

you need to use:
https://nghttp2.org/blog/2015/02/10/nghttp2-dot-org-enabled-http2-server-push/

> When you access https://nghttp2.org via HTTP/2 protocol, CSS file
>   /stylesheets/screen.css is pushed to client. If you inspect the
>   response header closely, you will find Link header field like this:

```
link: </stylesheets/screen.css>; rel=preload; as=stylesheet
```